# AngularJS how to caching request with $http and $cacheFactory

Tags: angularjs, caching, cachefactory

I have the next problem

I'm trying to caching a get request with $http but seems not working, the cache variable always get undefined

Sample code:

```
myApp.factory("sample", ["$http", "$q", "$cacheFactory", sample]);

function sample($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {
    function getData() {
        var url = "http://whatever ...";

        return $http.get(url, {
            params: {
                Id: 10
            },
            cache: true
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            // trying to get the cached data
            var cache = $cacheFactory.get("$http");
            var data = cache.get(url); // undefined -> ??

            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
    }

    return {
        getData: getData
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the URL which you are passing to get the cache.

This works.

```
myApp.factory("sample", ["$http", "$q", "$cacheFactory", sample]);

function sample($http, $q, $cacheFactory) {
    function getData() {
        var url = "http://whatever ...";

        return $http.get(url, {
            params: {
                Id: 10
            },
            cache: true
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            // trying to get the cached data
            var cache = $cacheFactory.get("$http");
            var data = cache.get(url+"?id=10"); // cacheFactory will store the cache data with full URL including params so your key should have the params
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
    }

    return {
        getData: getData
    };
}
```

cacheFactory will store the cache data with full URL including params so your key should have the params.

`cache.get(url+"?id=10");`